# ruby rest_client exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, rest-client

I try to use gem rest client to access some simple REST service, I have installed the rest-client following [these](http://rubygems.org/gems/rest-client) instructions, but when try to use the library, I get the following error `no such file to load -- rest_client`.

It seems that the library is not recognized.

Did anyone have similar problems with this library?

Comment: have you listed it in the gem file and updated with bundle install or bundle update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you add it to your Gemfile, bundle install, restart server, and if required, require 'rest_client' or whatever the file name is.